# why does it show me that "Cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Action'"

Tags: c#

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(MyMethodA).Invoke());  
    }
```

I don't know why I can not use "new Action(MyMethodA).Invoke()" as parameter to StartNew.

```
    private static void MyMethodA()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 100000; x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A - " + x);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're invoking the method with the call to `Invoke()`. This method will return the type specified by the `MyMethodA`, so void. Remove the call to invoke and it should work

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. it can run if I delete the Invoke(). but there is nothing printing out.

Comment: I just posted an answer including why it doesn't print out down below and how to fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code to this:

```
Task task = Task.Run(MyMethodA);
```

Your code is trying to run a task with what you're returning from your method, which is void.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `Invoke` method on a `Action` object will return the type of the method used to construct it. In your case that is `void`, this is because `.Invoke()` actually calls executes the method. But `Task.Factory.StartNew` requires an `Action` to be passed as the first parameter. Removing `.Invoke()` will solve your problem, meaning your code will looks like this:

```cs
Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(MyMethodA));
```

This however will not actually start your `Task`, as it only creates it. You'll need to run it manually later. Or if you want to create and run it right off the bat use `Task.Run` like so

```cs
Task t1 = Task.Run(MyMethodA)
```

Notice how I omitted `new Action(...)`, this is because the compiler is smart enough to figure it out on its own